# What would be the correct predicate/verb in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, predicate

> All in all, every parent and every child is/are different.

I know that subjects with 'every' count as singular, so in case I wanted to say *'Every parent is different'*, then I would have had to use 'is'. But this case makes me wonder, whether the subject is plural or singular, since it's 'every parent and every child'. I suppose it's the 'and' that confuses me.

Could someone please explain which is correct and why?

Answer (score 1):

In [Communication Skills for Professionals
By NIRA KUMAR](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=TjMPbd8814gC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=%22every+man+and+every+woman+are%22+-eve&source=bl&ots=7-lHtWVKwX&sig=4CdnbaHWZRcojf7wqR1uhm7zrWU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4wdf5krjRAhWMKcAKHRErALYQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q&f=false), the author writes:

> When compound subjects are modified by each/every, they are treated as
>   singular. For example,
>
> Every boy and girl was asked to follow the college rules.
>
> We cannot say:
>
> *In our factory every man and every woman are hardworking.

So,

*All in all, every parent and every child is different.*

There are two conflicting 'rules' one could apply, but here, there is a largely standard preference (though internet examples of plural agreement can readily be found).